# Script to emerge packages

Tags: bash, gentoo

I'm trying to write a bash function which checks if a package is installed and installs it if needed. Right now it always installs regardless.

```
install() {
    echo "checking if $1 is already installed"
    if [[ ! $(equery -q l $1 | grep -q "$1") ]]
    then
        emerge -v $1
    else
        echo "$1 is already installed"
    fi
}

install "oracle-jdk-bin"
```

- the output of `equery -q l $1` is `dev-java/oracle-jdk-bin-1.8.0.45`
- grep should find oracle-jdk-bin and return 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the "noreplace" option of emerge?

Description: "Skips the packages specified on the command-line that have already been installed. Without this option, any package atoms or package sets you specify on the command-line will cause Portage to remerge the package, even if it is already installed. Note that Portage will not remerge dependencies by default. This option can be used to update the world file without rebuilding the packages.", taken from https://dev.gentoo.org/~zmedico/portage/doc/man/emerge.1.html